# how can the awk command in Shell scripting be used to subtract integers in columns that also contain characters?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a txt file that looks something like this

```
col 1    col 2    col 3    col 4
A        12.6e12  058      12ED08
B        10.2e09  070      40ED01
C        13.5e08  046      73ED02
```

If I want to subtract the first 2 digits of col 4 from col 3, i.e. ignoring "ED" and the last 2 digits from col 4. how can I do this using awk command? and also if I want to add col 2 and col 3 using awk, how would I take the digits after 'e' to be the exponent? A simple output would be

```
col 1   col 4-col 3
A       -46           (12-058)
B       -30           (40-070)
C        27           (73-046)
```

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: Could you please provide an example output?

Answer (score 1):

Easy in Perl, should be similarly easy in awk:

```
perl -lane 'print $F[1] + $F[2], "\t", $F[3] - $F[2]' input-file
```

- `-n` pocesses the input line by line
- `-a` splits the input into the `@F` array
- `-l` appends a newline to `print`

Perl undestands the "scientific notation", so no work's needed to interpret the 12.6e12. When using arithmetic operators on strings, Perl tries to convert them into numbers by taking as many characters from the left as possible, so it ignores the `ED...` in col4.

Comment: @john.s: I explained each particular letter below the command line. See [perlrun](http://p3rl.org/perlrun) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

using `awk(1)`:

```
$ awk '{print $1 "\t" $4-$3 "\t(" int($4) "-" $3 ")"}' << EOF
> A        12.6e12  058      12ED08
> B        10.2e09  070      40ED01
> C        13.5e08  046      73ED02
> EOF
A       -46     (12-058)
B       -30     (40-070)
C       27      (73-046)
```

Comment: But in the awk command you did not specify that 'ED..' should not be included in the subtraction? what if i have to specify it myself?

Comment: what's your point? awk would scan number to int until next char is not a number, so as long as `ED` is not number, there's no need to explicitly specify. otherwise, you should use this:`awk '{$4 = substr($4, 0, 2); print $1 "\t" $4-$3 "\t(" int($4) "-" $3 ")"}'`

Comment: thanks thats what i needed. I know that awk does it automatically but i wanted to know how one can do it himself.

Comment: `awk '{sub(/\(.*\)ED*/, "\1", $4); print $1 "\t" $4-$3 "\t(" int($4) "-" $3 ")"}'`, this version you can specify `ED` to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Awk is your friend here:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]e]+|ED' 'FNR==1{print "col 1   col 4-col 3";next}{print $1 "\t" ($5-$4) "\t(" $5 "-" $4 ")"}' YourFile
```